# How to center 2 images within a single DIV

Tags: css, image, html, centering

I have a DIV tag that contains 2  tags. I want these figures to center themselves within the DIV, which is supposed to be centering itself within the middle of the page. How do I do this?

HTML:

```
<div class="images-captions">
    <figure><img src="images/Prop Pics/From Mike B aka StratosDadRI/intial-blueprinting_thumb.jpg" alt="Intial Blueprinting"><figcaption>After intinal blueprint</figcaption></figure>
    <figure><img src="images/Prop Pics/From Mike B aka StratosDadRI/after-damage_thumb.jpg" alt="After Damage"><figcaption>After damage</figcaption></figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.images-captions            { width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; }
.images-captions figure     { float: left; width: 250px; padding: 10px;}
.images-captions figcaption { text-align: center; font-style: italic;   }
```

Comment: center them, horizontally? vertically?

Comment: I actually want to center them horizontally and then divide the space between the figures and center them vertically. I have a header at the directly above the figures, and if they are centered properly, the header should be exactly in the middle between the two.

Answer (score 1):

### Center them horizontally

This case I would solve like this:

**CSS**

```
.images-captions {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.images-captions figure {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.images-captions figcaption {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/xKrCr/)

### Center them vertically

You can solve it like this:

**CSS**

```
.images-captions {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.images-captions figure {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.images-captions figcaption {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/xKrCr/1/)

Comment: I tried your code to center horizontally, but it still didn't work.

Comment: @LakeJeffler Does is work in the fiddle for you? Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by adding the text-align to the figure

```
.images-captions figure     { float: left; width: 250px; padding: 10px;text-align:center}
.images-captions figcaption { font-style: italic;   }
```

For understanding:
You want to align the text in the parent conatainer. So you have to add the attribute to the parent element and not the element itself

[DEMO on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kTfYM/)